# animating android live wallpaper

Tags: android, animation

I have created a live wallpaper of 5 images using android studio. The images change for every 5 seconds. Now I want to animate the images (fadein, fadeout, zoomout etc). How to do that?. I am not getting any way. Please suggest me.

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
               mImagesArray[mImagesArrayIndex]);
               canvasHelper.drawScaledImage(image, mImageScale);
```

Comment: have you use Animation methods in Android?

Comment: sorry, I don't know about animaton methods. Just I am thinking to animate using xml animation file. But I am not getting how to do it.

Comment: You can have a look here [Android Animation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm)

Comment: Instead of saying post code here

Comment: Thanks @flasify. But the link show the animation on imageview. I am drawing images on canvas in WallpaperService. I am stuck there.

Comment: ok @W4R10CK. I will do that